# Supabase - empty table and bulk insert data from MS Access db

Tags: node.js, ms-access, electron, supabase-database

I'm using supabase for a project. I have an odbc access database that will take data from an AS400 DB2 database, and into the electron app where I'm using the data, I need to update the supabase database everytime the app will start. At the moment I'm using this code with the upsert function of supabase, but I've noticed that sometimes this can duplicate the records, and this is not the desired result.

```js
ipcMain.on('startDatabaseUpdate', (event, ...args) => {
    suppliersdb.query('SELECT * FROM MDB_FANFOR0F_1')
        .then( (results) => {
            let count = 0
            results.forEach( (result, i) => {
                count++
                if( i === 0 ){
                    i++
                }
                result.NEMA = result.NEMA.replace('§', '@')
                //
                store.supabase.from('Suppliers')
                    .upsert([
                        { 
                            id: i, 
                            cod: result.CFOR,
                            name: result.XFOR,
                            cap: result.CCAP,
                            country: result.YLOC,
                            state: result.CPRO,
                            email: result.NEMA
                        }
                    ], { count: 'exact' }).select()
                    .then( (response) => {
                        //console.log(response)
                    }).catch( e =>  {
                        event.sender.send('databaseUpdateError', e)
                    })
            })
            //
            if( count === results.length ){
                event.sender.send('databaseUpdateCompleted', { suppliersCount: results.length })
            }
    }).catch( e => { 
        console.log(e) 
        event.sender.send('databaseUpdateError', e)
    })
```

Is there a function of supabase js client library I can use to remove all the data from the table and then insert the updated data from the mdb Access file??

Comment: Run a DELETE action SQL?

Comment: @June7 I've looked at the documentation of supabase and the js library have a delete method. I've tried it and seems working, but after the command I need to insert updated data, and it seems that the delete query still run during the upsert, so not all the data are added. need to find a solution

Comment: In VBA I would use `Do Loop Until something` or `Do Events` timer. I have no idea what you could do.

Comment: Is the `id` column in the `Suppliers` table not the primary key? Because if it is the primary key, then Supabase would never create duplicate data. I think it's better to focus on finding out why duplicate data is created with the upsert function and fix that.

Comment: @dshukertjr, no. Id is the primary key and inside the imported data from access there is no a defined primary key. Some data are present multiple time so it will take a bit of time to load the database. I will need to remove duplicates or modify the original query that is done in db2 before connect access to the data source

Comment: In the original imported data, is there any unique column? If there is, you could probably remove the `id` column and set the unique column as the primary key to solve all this.

Comment: @dshukertjr unfortunately some data are common shared across the columns. So i can't set a column as id to replace the one provided by supabase

Comment: So basically you want to wipe out the data and start a clean insert every single time?  You can just use the `delete` method of Supabase to do that. Make sure you run your insert after the delete operation is complete by properly handling your promisses. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: nice suggestion, I've noticed that every single wipe operation will return a promise, so instead of use a then block I will need to use the finally I think?